# Out of bounds error due to list assignment?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
array1 = []
array2 = []
size = int(input("Enter the size of the array: "))
print("Enter the elements in the array: ")
for item in range(size):
    element = int(input())
    array1.append(element)

array2[0] = -1
for item in range(1, 8):
    x = item-1
    if array1[item] < array1[x]:
        array2.append(-1)
    elif array1[item] > array1[x]:
        array2.append(array1[x])
    elif array1[item] == array1[x]:
        array2.append(array2[x])
print(array2)
```

Expected output: a proper execution of the code

Received output:

> Traceback (most recent call last)
>           array2[0] = -1
>       IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: On what  input did your recieve this error?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin: Any. `array2[0] = -1` when `array2` is initialised to `[]` is an error.

Comment: list_size: 8 , list elements: 39 27 11 4 24 32 32 1

Comment: This _is_ the proper execution of the code (i.e. given your code, I expect the execution to be the error you reported). Since you didn't specify what the code _should_ do, it's very hard to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @Amadan I think it's fair to assume that proper execution of the code does not include reaching an error mid-code.

Comment: You know what, you're right. @SankalanChakraborty, while in this case we were able to understand your problem and help with it, do know (for future questions) that it is important to provide an example input (like you did in a previous comment, in the future it should be in comment body) and expected output for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that your problem is in `array2`, so most of the code is superfluous to this issue. The [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your error is:

```
array2 = []
array2[0] = -1
```

When looking at this example, it's easier to see the problem - `array2` is initialized with size 0, so its 0-th index is already out of bound.

Going back to your code, you can just initialize it as `array2 = [-1]` instead of how it's written - after all, `array2[0] = -1` is the first time that `array2` is accessed. Or you can change the `array2[0]=-1` to an `.append`.

Comment: Itamar Mushkin thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped, please mark it as "accepted" (with the little green V). If you don't find it, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

u set `array2` as `[]`,so when u define `array2[0] = -1` the index is out of range